# Java JDBC driver and TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

Tags: java, jdbc

How I could determine if JDBC driver is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`? In my program the user configures connection parameters to database and he could use any JDBC driver in the class path. I want to know if the driver is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` before executing any statements. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DatabaseMetaData has a method supportsResultSetType(int type) that you could use to check if the ResultSet supports `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

Answer (score 1):

By [querying the type](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getType()) of result set. For example:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
 ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
 ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE
);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
System.out.println(
 "Is Type Forward Only: " + 
 (rs.getType() == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY)
);
```

Comment: Would this not throw a SQLFeatureNotSupportedException if the ResultSet did not support TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY?

Answer (score 0):

There are Drivers that don't support scrolling? Could you give an example? What does such a driver return, when you try to create a Statement/ResultSet that is SCROLL_SENSITIVE and then ask for the Type? Like this:

```
Connection con = ...;
Statement statement = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ...);
System.out.println(statement.getResultSetType());
```

Comment: here's a discussion of one that I came across : http://osdir.com/ml/db.sqlite.jdbc/2008-05/msg00048.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get DriverPropertyInfo from the driver, although I can't find a specific jdbc specification that describes what the driver must return. [This  reference](http://www.springerlink.com/content/p2374356534h0783/) may have more.